# Getting View state error on multiple Bulk uploading of list of attachments from VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a requirement to Upload List of attachments from VF page in one click but iam getting a view state error on uploading a bulk data. so I tried using "Remoting" even in remoting there are some limitation in passing the parameters and size. Iam passing the list of attachment each Attachment may consists of MB's of file. The challenging part is there is a option to upload 50 attachments in one go also, there are 5 data points in which each data point may have 10 attachment to upload. based on the values the page rereders, the below is the image of the VF page.
Need Help Asap.
Thanks in Advance.
[image]

Comment: What exactly is your problem when using remoting? Show you code + error message.

Answer (score 0):

There won't be a solution without limits. They might only be higher or lower.

I'm not sure if attachments are the right entity to store so many files at all. Consider an app like box.com with integration.

If you want to stick native, note that there are two different kinds of attachments in salesforce: attachments and chatter attachments. The later on come with higher limits.